# get all offspring of each element

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to build a function which is getting all elements colors in a webpage.
For that, I will need to run on all children of the body element and get all their offspring.

As you know, children may be varied ("TABLE", "P", "A", "H1" etc..) as you can see in the following picture I made:

[image: HTML TREE]

In addition, usually the determine style is belong to the last offspring, as you can see in the next picture:

[image]

Is there a general method **in JAVASCRIPT** for looping on all children of an element, no matter what type this element is, and get the last element offspring? 
P.S (in the above picture, the relevant offspring's are: "P", "TD".

Thank you,
Doron

Comment: My understanding would be you want: `[].filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName('*'),function(n) {return n.children.length == 0;})`

Comment: consider to use jquery. your job reduces to `$('*:empty').each( function ( idx, elem ) { /* do whatever with leaf nodes */ });`. using the framework comes with lots of additional advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for(var i = 0, l = allElements.length ; i < l; i++) {
    //get your colors here
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the hierarchy does not saved. How could I know that TD is the child of Table?

Comment: I thought you just needed to know all the colors

Answer (score 1):

Using Jquery

```
  var colors=[];
  $('*').each(function(){
  colors.push($(this).css('color'));
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mFrGe/

Answer (score 1):

This works! :)

```
var myEle = $('html');
$('*',myEle).filter(function(){ return !this.childElementCount });
```

My code works for all dom elements. (since I ran this code on `html`)

So instead of `html`, you can put in an `#id` or a `.class` or any `tag` and all its children would be selected. We then filter all these to get only the ones which themselves don't have any children.